# AWS Python lambda times out forever after first timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

**Problem:**

I have a python lambda that constantly receives data every second and puts it into *DynamoDB*. I noticed that after the first time DynamoDB takes a little more and the function times out, all the following calls also timeout and it never recovers.
The way to bring the lambda back to normal is to redeploy it.
When it starts timing out, it does not display any logs. It times out without executing any of the code.

Below is a picture of our console that represents the issue.

[image: aws lambda console]

In order to reproduce the issue faster with this function I did the following:

1. Redeploy it and see it is working fine.
2. Reduce the memory available to the lambda to the minimum and timeout to 1 second. This will cause the first timeout
3. Increase back the memory of the lambda to normal and even increase the timeout. However, the timeouts persist

**Is there a way to resolve this issue without having to redeploy?**

I have seen the same description of issue but with *nodejs* in this post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234417.

I haven't seen any description related with the python lambda env

**More information about the setup:**

> *Lambda environments tested:* python3.6 and python3.7
>
> *Tool to deploy lambda:* serverless 1.57.0
>
> *serverless plugins used:* serverless-python-requirements, serverless-wsgi
>
> I am **not** using any VPC for the lambda

Thank you for the help,

Comment: What is the Lambda function doing? Can you share the code? Are there any errors or other information in the Lambda function's logs that are relevant to your question?

Comment: I can't share the code, but it is fairly simple. It is a small lambda that puts data into dynamoDB. I have seen people complaining about the same issue with nodejs here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234417.
But I haven't seen anything related with Python.
There are no logs when it times out. It doesn't even start the normal code.

Comment: Please try to share a small example, removing all sensitive parts, that exhibits this problem. The WSGI part of this is unusual so it would be hard for those of us who don't use WSGI with serverless Python to attempt to repro.

Comment: Will try to isolate it and put in a repository so others can access

Comment: Check your DynamoDB metrics for throttling.

Comment: Hi @MatthewPope, it is a good thought. I had suspected something about it as well. However, I changed to on-demand on DynamoDB to avoid any problems with it and the lambda timeout behavior still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the trigger for the bug.
When the lambda function zip uploaded is too large, after the first time it times out, it never recovers!

My solution was to carefully strip out the unnecessary dependencies to make the package smaller.

I created a repository using a docker container for people to reproduce the issue more easily:

https://github.com/pedrohbtp/bug-aws-lambda-infinite-timeout

Thanks for the messages in the comments. I appreciate whoever takes time to try to help here in SO.